# Do I need " ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize .. " in the Android activity of a Xamarin Forms application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just installed Rg.Plugins.Popup into my application and in the wiki example I see that it has:

```
"ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)"

[Activity(Label = "X", MainLauncher = true,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```

My current Activity is this:

```
[Activity(Label = "X", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = false)]
```

For an XF app is it important to have the additional entry for ConfigurationChanges in the activity?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove it and you rotate the device, it will probably re-create the activity, meaning your App will appear to restart on rotation. Hence it is a good idea to keep those configuration change flags.

There are other flags you can use as well for resizing of activities when the software keyboard appears on screen as well. You can read more about [handling configuration changes on Android in their documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes).